# Understanding application Layering

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm trying to understand about the layering of the application as below picture. Like which technologies were working in which layers.

Currently, I have only know about overall knowledge but not a deeply and clearly details.

Can anyone help me with a guide sample application for this?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software design - migrate to programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx) could help you. The ideas are the same, the terms vary slightly.

Comment: @Configurer, the image you linked to assums MVC for application layer, note you can also try MVVM, very comfortable with WPF.